# Comparison test for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I cannot seem to find a divergent series that is smaller than $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}}$ to compare it with, while [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%201/sqrt%28n%5E2%20%2b%201%29%20from%201%20to%20inf) does. How can I use the comparison test to prove that the series diverges?

Comment: ${1\over\sqrt{n^2+1}}\ge{1\over\sqrt{n^2+n^2}} ={1\over\sqrt {2n^2}}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: for $n\ge1$,
$${1\over\sqrt{n^2+1}}\ge{1\over\sqrt{n^2+n^2}} ={1\over\sqrt {2n^2}}={1\over\sqrt2}\cdot{1\over n\vphantom{\sqrt2}}.$$

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use the asymtotic comparison
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}\sim_\infty \frac 1 n$$